# Why are we printing alarm in compact data logger?

Tags: datalogger, data-acquisition

I understood most of the things of compact data logger but could not understand why are we printing alarm? And how is that possible to print alarm? Can you share? Also why is there 2 way communication between digital indicator and printer? Should not there be just 1 way communication where digital indicator gets printed?

[image]

Comment: Your questions depend on the specific system requirements and specifications of your particular data logger.  What's the model number and manufacturer? Can you add a link to the datasheet or manual?  Without more specifics we could make some educated guesses, but not much else.

Comment: Maybe the datalogger is fancy enough to have an internal printer - you know the thermal paper types that print receipts out of point-of-sale terminals? What happens when it's out of paper? I'll bet the digital indicator says 'paper out'! How would it know without 2-way communciation?